# Is there a way to secure static files using owin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have a problem after implementing Owin and secured all controllers and webapi of a asp.net mvc site, using cookie and bearer token. All static files like javascripts , images and some html files are unsecured and can be downloaded without authorization.

So far I have tried to implement, staticfiles (using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles) and setting static files for a request path but without any sucess. For example this?

```
app.UseStaticFiles("/Scripts");
```

And I have tried , using web.config settings like this wich is mentiond in katana documentation, but from this point to lets say roleX should have access to imagesX and roleY to imageY ? nothing is mention in the documentation about that or even how to control the files.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

So question is how do i secure static files using owin and authorization cookie.
Do i have to write a own middle ware , checking each request if it is a static file, or is there any recomended package on nuget that solves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWIN way of doing this would be with some middleware. New asp.net core will not support web.config and modules. Just be sure to plugin your auth middleware before static file middleware. It really depends what's your authentication and authorization framework of choice, but you can check an example here: https://coding.abel.nu/series/owin-authentication/

Comment: Is this realy the only way to do it?

Comment: Auth is your app responsibility. You can use some of-the-shelf framework to do cookie validation and all that (even writing your specific middlwware can be done in few line of the code). But yes, pipeline model where you can stop processing of a request by no calling next middleware is the way how you should do it.

Comment: Ok, so it's all cooking down to a method checking the request path , and ignoring some parts if not authorized. , thanks for the input

Comment: Yes, specially Map appBuilder method is handy for mapping middleware just for specific url path https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337263(v=vs.113).aspx